# How to use <GPUImage:JFAVoronoi+VoronoiConsumer> with a still image?

Tags: gpuimage

### brief

> i have trouble when using the
>   GPUImageJFVoronoiFilter+GPUImageVoronoiConsumerFilter
>   to process a still image, anyone could give a help to look at it?
>   thanks.
>  
>   
>  
>   i referred to the  example  case GPUIMAGE_VORONOI in
>   FilterShowcase ,the below is pictures and my code and result
>  picture(which seemed abnormal):

### input_pictures:

> stillImage lena.jpg:
>
> > http:     //i.stack.imgur.com/ce59q.jpg
>
> voroni_points2.png:
>
> > http:     //i.stack.imgur.com/CsP8G.png
>
> WID-small.jpg:
>
> > http:     //i.stack.imgur.com/JKBFl.jpg

### code

```
///================================================   
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
GPUImagePicture *sourcePicture;

//the example  use videoCamera    
//videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
//videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

///i use still image: 
GPUImagePicture * stillImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“lena.jpg”]];

BOOL needsSecondImage = NO;  
needsSecondImage = YES; 

GPUImageJFAVoronoiFilter *jfa = [[GPUImageJFAVoronoiFilter alloc] init];
[jfa setSizeInPixels:CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0)];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"voroni_points2.png"]];
[sourcePicture addTarget:jfa];
filter = [[GPUImageVoronoiConsumerFilter alloc] init];
[jfa setSizeInPixels:CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0)];
[(GPUImageVoronoiConsumerFilter *)filter setSizeInPixels:CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0)];

 //the example  use videoCamera    
 //[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
 ///i use still image: 
[stillImage addTarget:filter];
[jfa addTarget:filter];
[sourcePicture processImage];

UIImage *inputImage;
///i don’t understand why to add this step ,i just copy the example codes
///in FilterShowcase
inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WID-small.jpg"];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[sourcePicture processImage];
[sourcePicture addTarget:filter];

//the example  use videoCamera      
//[filter addTarget:filterView];
//[videoCamera startCameraCapture];

///i use still image: 
[stillImage processImage];
[filter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
UIImage * filteredImage;
filteredImage = [filter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];

[self.selectedImageView setImage:filteredImage];

///==============================================
```

### result

> after comparing with the result of this link
>   http:   //unitzeroone.com/labs/jfavoronoi/
>   which is mentioned in GPUImageJFAVoronoiFilter.m,
>  
>   i got the strange result,obviously, this seemed not the expected result of voronoi:
>  
>   
>  
>   result.png:
>
> > https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrx7D.png

Answer (score 0):

i modified the GPUImageJFAVoronoi.* and GPUImageVoronoiConsumer.* to let
stillImage work,for details refer to:
    https://github.com/ihgazni/voronoi_modified_GPUImage